# Program not running at all?

Tags: installed-programs

I have a program that I want to run and when I click the icon, nothing happens. I also will run the program from terminal and nothing happens either. I tried running this program on a distro it wasn't made for, on Centos, and the GUI of the program opened when I clicked the icon as well as starting the program through terminal.

However when I try to do the same thing on the distro it was made for, Ubuntu, I'm getting nothing. What can I do to figure out what is going on here? No notification telling me there's an error,nothing both clicking on the icon that was created when I installed it and going to the bin directory and using terminal to run it.

Comment: `ls -l file` to see permissions, `file file` to see what the `file` looks like, `ldd file` to see if it needs a shared library you don't have. `mount` to see if the volume containing the directory containing `file` is mounted with the `noexec` option, `strace file` to watch `file`'s execution.

Comment: I ran the strace and on the Centos, it exits with a code 0 while on Ubuntu it exits with code 13?